# Can't output logs in JSON pretty print format using logback

Tags: java, spring-boot, grafana, logback, opensearch

I'm setting up logging in a Spring Boot microservice. I want the logs to be displayed in json format (ideally in pretty-print format). The logs should display correctly both in my IDE and in a visualization system (such as OpenSearch, Grafana, etc.).
The problem lies in the display of logs in the visualization system:

**1 option. Pretty print format (logback.xml)**

```
<configuration>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>

<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout">
            <jsonFormatter class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
                <prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint>
            </jsonFormatter>
            <timestampFormat>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ</timestampFormat>
            <includeContextName>false</includeContextName>
            <appendLineSeparator>true</appendLineSeparator>
        </layout>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</root>
```

**Problem: Each line of json will be logged separately.**
[image]

**2 option. Custom pattern (logback.xml)**

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>

<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
        <providers>
            <timestamp>
                <timeZone>UTC</timeZone>
            </timestamp>
            <mdc/>
            <pattern>
                <pattern>
                    {
                    "method": "%mdc{method}",
                    "url": "%mdc{url}",
                    "level": "%level",
                    "thread": "%thread",
                    "logger": "%logger",
                    "message": "%message"
                    }
                </pattern>
            </pattern>
            <stackTrace/>
        </providers>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</root>
```

**Problem: Separate logs are collected into one log.**
[image]

**Dependencies (pom.xml):** Spring Boot version 3.0.1.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-json-classic</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This might help you. Try JSONEventLayoutV1 instead of JsonLayout as layout.

https://github.com/logstash/log4j-jsonevent-layout